# Why does laravel query problem with PLUS sign

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am fetching a simple record from database using following query:

`$user = User::where('email','myemail+33@gmail.com')->first();` and its returning an empty result.

but when I tried to match other email for example:

`$user = User::where('email','myemail@gmail.com')->first();` this one return the proper object.

It seems like plus sign is stripping from ORM but not sure anybody face and resolve problem like this before ?

Comment: Does the email address come from a URL parameter?

Comment: Which version of laravel you are using? on version 6 return correct result

Comment: @ceejayoz email address is sending through post.

Comment: @Mohsen I am using Laravel 7.2.5

Comment: @ceejayoz even in above example I hardcoded the values but it still not giving me proper result.